# URLs not working

Tags: django, django-urls

My URLs for my application looks like this:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 (r'^contractManagement/login', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'},()),
 (r'^contractManagement/logout', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.logout_view'),
 (r'^contractManagement/', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.index'),
 (r'^accounts/profile/(?P<contract>[^/]+)/edit$', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.editContract'), 
 (r'^accounts/profile/(?P<contract>[^/]+)/$', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.viewContract'),
 (r'^accounts/profile/$', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.loggedIn'),
 (r'^accounts/profile/newContract$', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.addContract'),
 (r'^accounts/profile/newClient$', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.addClient'),            
 (r'^accounts/profile/logout$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'LoggedOut.html'},()),
```

I am now getting an error No Contract matches the given query. This is a 404 error. I don't know why the views for `/accounts/profile/newContract/` don't require a contract. If you need anything else leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django URL patterns are processed in order.  It looks like your `/accounts/profile/newContracts/` URL is matching your r`'^accounts/profile/(?P<contract>[^/]+)/$'` pattern.

Try moving your `r'^accounts/profile/newContract$'` pattern higher up.  (and fix the missing 's' typo)

But more importantly, make sure you have a URL scheme that's not ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah I know this is a little test application for my brother to show the simplicity of using Django over rails.

Comment: Sorted. it needed to be higher up and r'^accounts/profile/newContract/$'

Comment: How about trailing slash / no slash?

Answer (score 0):

(r'^accounts/profile/newContract$'
newContract - Without s.
And you go to the /accounts/profile/newContracts . With s at end
And if you to newContracts it will matcht this url :
  (r'^accounts/profile/(?P[^/]+)/$', 'contractManagement.contracts.views.viewContract'),
 And will look for newContracts

Comment: Sorry my mistake was typing really quickly didn't mean to put that there.